# Windows File Explorer preview for every GCode images C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, g-code

I can generate images from GCode files, but I don't know how to add a preview in Windows File Explorer for every image.

I would like to achieve this:
[LINK](http://thumbnailcnc.com/)

I never done this

PS. I'm using .Net C# WinForms.

Thanks advanced,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

You could create your own dialog service. 
[image]